# Filter Ethernet packets with C++ in linux Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, networking

I want to filter packets that receives (or sends) is a network , I don't want a copy of them , I want to filter the packet and if necessary drop that packet. so i want to access to that packet in Ethernet layer, I want to filter packets like `ARP` too.

I want to do this in linux , Ubuntu and I use C++ , QT.

Can anyone help me with a library or something else ? or something line a book or jurnal that do this thing. I searched for NETFilter before , but that couldn't help me.

Thanks

Comment: you want to implement wireshark? you can use pcap library.. anyway this is too broad question, it will be closed

Comment: Guys I want to write OS which will have window manager and permission control, Please provide library and how to do it in c++

Comment: @otopolsky why it will be closed? no woteshark is something that only show the packets , i want to control to packets before get to OS , and if i want , drop them .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic point 4, @nosbor thats a good one :D

Comment: You need to write a ethernet network driver for linux

Comment: Your best bet is creating a raw socket and putting the interface in promiscuous mode : this will give you access to all packets that the card can "see" arriving on the physical interface - this is how programs like Wireshark or tcpdump work. However, you can't filter them out once the kernel receives them - you need to use `iptables` for that, or write your own solution from scratch.

Comment: @ArianB If you want to filter network packets before the kernel sees them, you're not going to do it in qt, for starters. I recommend more general experience before attempting this. Take some classes at your local university. Search for some textbooks about networking and hardware design.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not implement packet capturing functionality for link layer. You can use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to capture packets on Linux. Your program almost certainly will need root privileges to use network interface that way.

Comment: this is in Ethernet layer?

Comment: @ArianB Yes, Ethernet is link layer protocol in terms of tcpdump and OSI model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a ethernet network driver for linux. At socket level you attach a filter so that only packets matching your filter's rules are accepted and passed to the socket. 
This [link](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4852?page=0,0) will be a good start.